# image submit button

Tags: forms

I am trying to update records with a image button.  here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['unstar'])) {
    echo "good!";
}
?>
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='image' src='http://mysite.com/images/starIcon.png' name='unstar' id='unstar' />
</form>
```

When I click on the image, it does not echo "good".  what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not giving `unstar` a value, so it won't be detected as Set by the function.

Comment: I thought that $_post goes by name?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code and apparently when you click on the image button, php generates the following post values `unstar_x` and `unstar_y`, both of which correspond to the x and y coordinates of where you clicked the button.

Try changing it to the following and you'll see what I mean:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='image' src='http://mysite.com/images/starIcon.png' name='unstar' id='unstar' />
</form>
```

**EDIT**

So if you just need to see if the button was pressed to submit the form, you can just do the following, which just checks if `unstar_x` or `unstar_y` was set.

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['unstar_x']) || isset($_POST['unstar_y'])){
    echo "Good";
}
?>

<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='image' src='http://mysite.com/images/starIcon.png' name='unstar' id='unstar' value="testing" />
</form>
```

You should note that the output of $_POST will not include the value `Testing`. At least on my system, I don't get a value when I submit the image button.

Comment: what? lol that's weird! so how would I get it to do what I need it to do?

Comment: You could just check if one or both of those values are set. If you add a value attribute, the image button does not send the value. So you may want to use a regular a submit button and use a css background image for the button.